# Running loop in linux and cloning repos one by one and fetch data from them

Tags: linux, scripting, git, repository

i have a file 'X' in which i have listed all the repos. now i want to run a loop in linux so that it picks up 1 repo at a time, clone that repo, go into the folder, fetch last commit person and last commit date of the repo. 
loop end.

Answer (score 0):

No one will build the entire script for you, but to get you started here would be an option for the loop, where you just need to add all actions that you want to perform for each repo in the file.

```
for repo in $(cat fileX); do
    git clone $repo
    ... # add what you want to do
    done
```